# What weapon upgrades make their corresponding proving ground significantly easier?

Tags: bastion

The upgrade `Tracking Critters` causes each shot to automatically hit the target.  I found the Fang Repeater 1st prize challenge impossible to complete without the upgrade, and extremely easy with. This has already been covered for the [pike](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29190/how-to-win-the-pike-proving-ground), [machete](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28544/how-to-win-the-machete-proving-grounds), [breakers bow](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28393/whats-the-optimal-solution-to-the-breakers-barracks-challenge) and [fang repeater](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28418/how-do-i-improve-my-score-in-the-trapper-shingle-challenge) proving grounds on the site.

Are there any other weapon upgrades that make the associated challenge trivially easy, or have a significant impact on performance?

Comment: This has already been addressed for four of the eight proving grounds on our site. I've edited your question to include references to these to narrow its focus to the proving grounds not already covered on our site. Feel free to rollback my edit if you have a problem with this.

Comment: Uhh...for the Fang Repeater, if you hold down shift while firing it auto-aims at targets. You don't need any upgrades to 1st prize the eight challenges.

Comment: @Kotsu, I don't believe any upgrades are necessary.  However, the auto-targeting makes the challenge unbelievably simple.

Comment: @Toast Yes it does but again, you could have cleared the challenge with very little problems by using **shift**, which does what auto aim does albeit with an extra key input and a tiny bit of aiming.

Comment: @Kotsu, I was using shift.  Still couldn't get first.  Not sure what point you're trying to make.

Comment: @Toast I know a lot of people have issues with that challenge, so just wanted to point that out in case you didn't know.

Comment: For the fang repeater just having the first 50% reload time is all that is needed... its not that hard, just fire all your bolts and run to reload, rinse and repeat. Also use your roll to get ahead faster.

Comment: The Fire Bellows challenge is significantly easier with Lasting Burn and Cripple. Those birds are a pain when they get out of your range and squawk around - this lets you tag them and easily catch up if they don't die from the damage over time.

Comment: Also Brusher's Pike challenge is mostly your choice of route (hint: a fast route goes bottom left, mid, then bottom right) - but if you choose Throw Reload Speed, Crit Damage, and Werewhiskey (100% crit when under 33% HP) messily walk to the first point to hurt yourself, then you will one shot multiple pincushions with a single throw. It makes the run a joke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't remember for sure, but Power String should help with the Breaker's Bow proving ground. Impact Shells and Expanded Chamber can make the Scrap Musket challenge trivial.

Beyond that, I'm at a loss for now.

Comment: I beat the Scrap Musket proving ground on my first try thanks to Impact Shells and Expanded Chamber.  Knockback ftw.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, for the challenges it's best to spec for the speed/reload upgrades as opposed to damage (The Calamity Cannon and Army Carbine in particular benefit from this).

Comment: Having both reload advantages for Army Carbine makes it a cakewalk. You just have to remember to move to keep things in range.

Answer (score 3):

The Werewhiskey spirit, which gives you 100% critical hits, helps a lot on the repeater, pistol, bow, and pike challenges ... and possibly others. Before starting the challenge, jump off the ledge to lose health until it activates. Then you'll be able to one-shot everything.